# C# nesting - access member of outer type

Tags: c#, class, nested

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Nested type problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393432/nested-type-problem)

Let's say I have this code:

```
public class Tree
{
    private readonly int nodeCapacity;
    public int NodeCapacity { get { return nodeCapacity; } }

    public Tree(int nodeCapacity)
    {
        this.nodeCapacity = nodeCapacity;
    }

    private class Node
    {
        object[] objects;
        Node()
        {
            objects = new object[nodeCapacity];
        }
    }
}
```

This doesn't compile and gives this error:

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type...

Is there a way to access that non-static member of outer type (from nested class) without passing the variable via constructor parameter nor using "static" keyword?

Comment: You can let the `Node` have a `parent`, from which you can retrieve the `NodeCapacity`. All you have to do it set it during initialisation (probably here as a constructor parameter). Or else you can just pass the `nodeCapacity` as a parameter.

Comment: why don't you make the readonly field a constant ... then it would be static as well

Comment: Even though the class `Node` is declared inside `Tree`, an instance of `Node` has no relationship to a `Tree` instance until you define one.

Comment: i get that you dont want to make it a static property, but why dont you want to pass it through a constructor?

Comment: @MUG4N I can't have it static, because I need to have multiple trees with different node capacities.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis Yes, but via nesting I have better encapsulation, because I can access the Node class and Node objects only from Tree class.

Comment: _I need to have multiple trees with different node capacities_ - then how should the Node know _which_  capacity? That's the reason for your problem.

Comment: @NikolasJíša true, but it doesn't change the rules of class<->instance relationship between the two. Only the _visibility_ of the members change - so your problem would not be different from two unrelated classes.

Comment: @JaneDoe I don't want to waste memory so 10000 nodes don't hold the same variable (this is simplified example and here I pass indirectly to Node.objects.Length that value...)

Comment: I guess I have my answer now I didn't know that these nested classes aren't related at all (except that visibility), thanks everyone

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would like to ask if there is a way to access that non-static member of outer type (from nested class) without passing the variable via constructor parameter nor using "static" keyword.

No, there is no way to access an instance variable of the outer class from within the nested class.

In C#, nested classes are completely separate instances, and have no direct relation to the outer class instance.  You would need to pass a specific instance of `Tree` into the `Node` constructor.

```
Node(Tree parent)
{
    objects = new object[parent.nodeCapacity];
}
```

This way, when the `Tree` creates it's nodes, it can pass `this` to the constructor, and it will be read correctly.  There is no real downside here, though.  Since `Node` has private accessibility, only `Tree` instances could ever construct an instance in any case.