# Cannot access a non-static member of outer type via nested type

Tags: c#, class

I have error

> Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'Project.Neuro' via
>   nested type 'Project.Neuro.Net'

with code like this (simplified):

```
class Neuro
{
    public class Net
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            int x = OtherMethod(); // error is here
        }
    }

    public int OtherMethod() // its outside Neuro.Net class
    {
        return 123;  
    }
}
```

I can move problematic method to Neuro.Net class, but I need this method outside.

Im kind of objective programming newbie.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious - `OtherMethod` is a member of another type.  The fact that it's nested does not mean the methods are _inherited_.

Comment: See this SO answer for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5393472/1451531

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that *nested* classes are not *derived* classes, so the methods in the outer class are not *inherited*.

Some options are

1. Make the method `static`:

   ```
   class Neuro
   {
       public class Net
       {
           public void SomeMethod()
           {
               int x = Neuro.OtherMethod(); 
           }
       }

       public static int OtherMethod() 
       {
           return 123;  
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use inheritance instead of nesting classes:

   ```
   public class Neuro  // Neuro has to be public in order to have a public class inherit from it.
   {
       public static int OtherMethod() 
       {
           return 123;  
       }
   }

   public class Net : Neuro
   {
       public void SomeMethod()
       {
           int x = OtherMethod(); 
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create an instance of `Neuro`:

   ```
   class Neuro
   {
       public class Net
       {
           public void SomeMethod()
           {
               Neuro n = new Neuro();
               int x = n.OtherMethod(); 
           }
       }

       public int OtherMethod() 
       {
           return 123;  
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I made my method static. Now im wondering how shall I reorganize my classes... maybe its good subject for another question.

Answer (score 2):

you need to instantiate an object of type `Neuro` somewhere in your code and call `OtherMethod` on it, since `OtherMethod` is not a static method. Whether you create this object inside of `SomeMethod`, or pass it as an argument to it is up to you. Something like:

```
// somewhere in the code
var neuroObject = new Neuro();

// inside SomeMethod()
int x = neuroObject.OtherMethod();
```

alternatively, you can make `OtherMethod` static, which will allow you to call it from `SomeMethod` as you currently are.

Comment: @Kamil don't worry about it, D Stanley's answer is more complete anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Even though class is nested within another class, it is still not obvious which instance of outer class talks to which instance of inner class. I could create an instance of inner class and pass it to the another instance of outer class. 
Therefore, you need specific instance to call this `OtherMethod()`.

You can pass the instance on creation:

```
class Neuro
{
    public class Net
    {
        private Neuro _parent;
        public Net(Neuro parent)
        {
         _parent = parent;
        }
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            _parent.OtherMethod(); 
        }
    }

    public int OtherMethod() 
    {
        return 123;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think making an instance of outer class in inner class is not a good option because you may executing business logic on outer class constructor. Making static methods or properties is better option. If you insist making an instance of outer class than you  should add another parameter to outer class contructor that not to execute business logic.