# How to access spriteBatch.Draw from another created class?

Tags: c#, xna

I am trying to access the draw method from a class that I created to draw sprites based on a randomly generated number. The error I get when I attempt to access those is this:

> Error 1   Cannot access a non-static member of outer type

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
        {
            GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
            SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
            Texture2D EarthGrass;
            Texture2D EarthDirt;
            Texture2D PooperMachoOre;
            Vector2 BlockBrush;
            System.Random IDB = new System.Random(1);
            System.Random IDB2 = new System.Random(5);

            public Game1()
            {
                graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
                Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

            }

            public class WorldGenerationOverall
            {
                System.Random IDB = new System.Random();
                Vector2 BlockBrush = new Vector2(0, 300);


                public WorldGenerationOverall()
                {
                    int constructer = 0;
                    constructer += 1;

                }
                public void Generate0H()
                {
                    BlockBrush.X = 300;
                }
                public void GenerateHeight10()
                {             
                    for (BlockBrush.Y = 320; BlockBrush.Y < 500; BlockBrush.Y += 20)
                    {
                        for (BlockBrush.X = 0; BlockBrush.X < 820; BlockBrush.X += 20)
                        {
                            int IDBint = IDB.Next(11);
                            if (IDBint == 10)
                            {                            
                                spriteBatch.Draw(PooperMachoOre, BlockBrush, Color.White);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                spriteBatch.Draw(EarthDirt, BlockBrush, Color.White);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public override void Initialize()
            {
                // TODO: Add your initialization logic here            
                BlockBrush = new Vector2(0, 300);
                WorldGenerationOverall super = new WorldGenerationOverall();
                base.Initialize();

            }

            protected override void LoadContent()
            {
                // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
                spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
                WorldGenerationOverall super = new WorldGenerationOverall();


                // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
                EarthDirt = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Ground/EarthDirt");
                EarthGrass = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Ground/EarthGrass");
                PooperMachoOre = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Sprites/Ores/PooperMachoOre");
            }


            public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
            {
                GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

                // TODO: Add your drawing code here\ 
                spriteBatch.Begin();
                WorldGenerationOverall super = new WorldGenerationOverall();
                super.Generate0H();
                super.GenerateHeight10();
                spriteBatch.End();

                base.Draw(gameTime);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320935/cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type-via-nested-type

Comment: I checked the page and it shows inheritance and static class types, but not how I would implement that into the XNA draw method as in the spriteBatch.Draw that it created when an XNA Project is created.

Comment: Try moving your `WorldGenerationOverall` class out of your game class and then pass the Game's `spritebatch` to the `WorldGenerationOverall.GenerateHeight10()` void by doing `WorldGenerationOverall.GenerateHeight10(SpriteBatch spritebatch)`, or just have a spritebatch property in the `WorldGenerationOverall` class and when you initialize the `WorldGenerationOverall`, set its `spritebatch` property to that of the main game's.

Comment: how could I reference the loadcontent method so that i can access the load lines for my sprites

Comment: Try something like `WorldGenerationOverall.LoadContent(ContentManager content){}`, and call this from your `Game.LoadContent`. Or you can have public variables in your `WorldGenerationOverall` class that you assign in the game's `LoadContent` method. Just out of curiosity, why do you have the `WorldGenerationOverall` inside your `Game` class?

Comment: I don't know... I could change that. This file was just a test for my generation concept.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass your `SpriteBatch` through the arguments in the method like so:

```
public void GenerateHeight10(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
      //Do stuff with spriteBatch
}
```

---

```
WorldGenerationOverall super = new WorldGenerationOverall();
super.Generate0H();
super.GenerateHeight10(spriteBatch);
```

Also, just curious, why are you making a new `WorldGenerationOverall` object each frame?