# Nested type c# countdown timer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to edit a textview from inside a countdown in Xamarin but it gives me the error

```
cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type via nested type
```

Here is the code

```
public class myCount : CountDownTimer
{
    public myCount(long millisInFuture, 
                   long countdownIntervall) : base(millisInFuture,countdownIntervall)
    {

    }

    public override void OnFinish ()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Done");
    }

    public override void OnTick (long millisUntilFinished)
    {
        countdownText = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimerText);
        countdownText.Text = ("" + millisUntilFinished);
        Console.WriteLine ("test" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
    }
}
```

In short, how do i access the TextView with OnTick() ?

Comment: Why don't you switch to a .NET timer?

Answer (score 1):

Make a static string `member` and update its contents regularly with `countdownText.Text`

You do this by using a timer to call an event that sets `countdownText.Text` equal to  `member`'s content every second.

Comment: Could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign `countdownText` in the outer scope. But since you are finding the view at that time, you don't need to do that. Use this instead:

```
TextView ct  = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimerText);
ct.Text = ("" + millisUntilFinished);
```

In your update you are passing in a TextView in the constructor. If that is the TextView you want to update, just assign it to a member variable inside the CountDownTimer class.

Comment: If I do it your way I get an error in the findviewbyID saying "cannot access a non static member of outer type via nested type."

Comment: See my update. Since you passed in the view into the the constructor, you can assign that to a member and just access it directly.

Comment: This got me a step closer, and I got access the TextView from myCount, but still not onTick()

Answer (score 0):

Is `myCount` nested within an `Activity` or `Fragment`? EG:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    // ...

    public class myCount : CountDownTimer
    {
        // ...
    }  
}
```

If so, then calling `FindViewById` within the `myCount` class scope will resolve to a non-static method in its owning class (the outer type). As `FindViewById` is an instance method for `Activity`, the compiler interprets the call on `FindViewById` as invoking a static method and generates an error. The compiler is basically interpreting your code like this: `MyActivity.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimerText);`. The scoping of `myCount` hides the real cause of this problem.

Here is a nice example that shows the error: [Cannot access a non-static member of outer type via nested type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320935/cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type-via-nested-type)

To fix this error, pass a reference to the owning `Activity` when creating the `myCount` timer object:

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        var timer = new myCount (1000, 100, this); // Inject reference to owning Activity.
        timer.Start ();
    }

    public class myCount : CountDownTimer
    {
        Activity m_owner;
        public myCount(long millisInFuture, 
            long countdownIntervall, Activity owner) : base(millisInFuture,countdownIntervall)
        {
            m_owner = owner;
        }

        public override void OnFinish ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Done");
        }

        public override void OnTick (long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            var countdownText = m_owner.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.countdownTimerText); // Invoke on parent instance.
            countdownText.Text = ("" + millisUntilFinished);
            Console.WriteLine ("test" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
    }  
}
```