# Why I get error when I add Response.Write to the method

Tags: c#

In my c# code I add Response command to display properties:

```
 var c = "some text";
 Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));
 Response.End();
```

Here is method:

```
    public Dictionary<string, string> GetMarkupFeatures()
    {

        //Hashtable features = new Hashtable();
        Dictionary<string, string> features = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        MgResourceIdentifier featureSourceId = new MgResourceIdentifier(libraryPath + this.GetMarkupName() + ".FeatureSource");

        var opt = new MgFeatureQueryOptions();
        var filter = GetParameter(args, "WHERE");
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter))
        {
            opt.SetFilter(filter);
        }

        var ftr = features.OrderBy(x=>x.Value).ToDictionary(x=>x.Key, x=>x.Value);

         var c = "some text";
            Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));
            Response.End();

        return ftr; 
    }
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0038: Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'System.Web.UI.Page' via nested type 'ASP.data_editdata_aspx.DataEditor'

on this row:

```
  Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));
```

Any idea why I get error above when I add Response commands?

Comment: Which line of code shows this error? Can you share the stack trace of the error? What functionality you are trying to achieve by setting response content?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I get error on this row:

  Response.Write(string.Format("{0}", c));

Comment: Tip: Avoid `Response.End()` because it causes a `ThreadAbortException` (it's a legacy from Classic ASP). You should call `Context.HttpApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()` instead.

Comment: @Dai where can I see the text?

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because you're trying to access a field of a class from its nested class. As written in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0038) documentation:

> A field in a class is not automatically available to a nested class.
>   To be available to a nested class, the field must be static.
>   Otherwise, you must create an instance of the outer class.

To fix the problem, you have 3 options:

1. Make the method/field you want to access *static*.
2. Use inheritance instead of nesting classes.
3. Create an instance of outer class.

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320935/cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type-via-nested-type) for more information.