# Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text recordd;
    string filePath;
    string jsonString;

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Personaje
    {
        public string nombre;
        public string profesion;
        public int nivel;

        public override string ToString ()
        {                           
            return string.Format ("{0}: {1} nivel {2}", nombre, profesion, nivel);
        }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class ListaPersonajes
    {
        public List<Personaje> personajes;

        public void Listar () {
            //loop cada objeto lista
            foreach (Personaje personaje in personajes) {
                Debug.Log(personaje);
                Debug.Log(personaje.nombre);

                recordd.text = "" + personaje; //// THIS LINE ERROR WHY??
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Error CS0038: Cannot access a nonstatic member of outer type 'ScoreManager' via nested type 'ScoreManager.ListaPersonajes'

Comment: Did you review other questions like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320935/cannot-access-a-non-static-member-of-outer-type-via-nested-type?

Answer (score 1):

Your'e trying to access the field recordd in the parent class.
The field isn't marked as static(and you probably don't want it to be static), and so the access is illegal.
You need to have an instance of ScoreManager  to access the redordd

---

Edit:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ScoreManager scoreManager = InitializeMonoBehaviour(); // This is what you need to figure out, how to properly init the object.
        List<Personaje> personajes = new List<Personaje>();
        /*
            fill personajes 
        */
        foreach (Personaje personaje in personajes)
        {
            Debug.Log(personaje);
            Debug.Log(personaje.nombre);

            scoreManager.AppendText(personaje.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text recordd;
    string filePath;
    string jsonString;

    publlic void AppendText(string text)    
    {
        this.recordd.text += text;
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Personaje
{
    public string nombre;
    public string profesion;
    public int nivel;

    public override string ToString ()
    {                           
        return string.Format ("{0}: {1} nivel {2}", nombre, profesion, nivel);
    }
}
```

I removed *ListaPersonajes* class (currently I don't see a reason for it) and added *AppendText(string text)* method to *ScoreManager* class.
After you initialize the class, you can iterate through the list and append the text. I also replaced the *""+personaje* syntax with a call to *ToString()*

Comment: I try this, no work: ScoreManager sm = new ScoreManager();
    sm.recordd.text=""+personaje;

Comment: @jesus_ That won't work. You create a new object, modify the value, and then throw the object away. You also can't call `new` on MonoBehavior objects *and* `recordd` would be null.

Comment: try this no work: ScoreManager.recordd.text=""+personaje;

Comment: If not familiar with unity and the MonoBehavior object, but it seems like using a c'tor isn't the intended usage of this object, like @Draco18s said. Check out this post: https://answers.unity.com/questions/862032/c-constructor-in-monobehaviour.html to understand ho to use the ScoreManager properly. I'll edit the first reply for a more complete exmaple.

Comment: @jesus_ That doesn't work either, `recordd` isn't `static`.